# WebRTC Android Native Insertable Streams

Tags: java, android, webrtc

How to use Insertable Streams in Webrtc application developed using Android Native library?
Is it possible to implement custom video frame processing by sender and receiver using Java code?
Came across https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/refs/heads/main/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/FrameEncryptor.java but it does not allow processing the frames in Java code.

Any help in this direction is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am also researching about this and, found that libwebrtc doesn't support this (not confirmed) I am also totally new new.